# Do Salesforce CMS records that reference an external URL count against the 500 limit?

Tags: lightning-experience, b2b, experience-cloud, salesforce-cms

Currently, we have all images for our purposes stored in a separate cloud server and can access those images via URL.  We are using B2B Commerce LEX which leverages Experience Builder, and the OOTB search results for products use the CMS to pull display images for products.  We have the limited license for CMS - meaning, we are capped at 500 CMS records.  My question is, if what we enter only references external URLs (as opposed to uploading images into Salesforce), does that still count against our 500 record limit?

As an aside, is there any way - perhaps via SOQL or API - that we can see how much of that limit has been used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer once and for all for the first part today by performing a bulk load -
you are NOT capped to only 500 records when your CMS entries reference external sources!

I still am unaware of any mechanism for checking how much of the limit has been used unfortunately.